# Why is date from Psql through Swift (Vapor) to JQuery via Ajax 31 years behind?

Tags: jquery, json, swift, postgresql, date

In a Swift (Vapor) server, I retrieve an object with a date field from a Postgres database. The correctness of the data is verified in the DB. I then encode the object:

```
    func sendToSocket(_ game: Game) {
    if Network.ownerWS == nil { return }
    var payload : String = ""
    do {
        payload = try String( data: JSONEncoder().encode(game), encoding: .utf8)!
    } catch {
        print("oops couldn't encode payload")
    }
    Network.ownerWS!.send(payload)
    }
```

This sends the resulting object via a web socket to a monitoring screen.

On that client, the message is received by a JS/JQuery function, which happens just fine:

```
     ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
        var received_msg = evt.data;
         var game = JSON.parse(received_msg)
         console.log(received_msg)
         …
         console.log(game.started)
         console.log(new Date(game.started * 1000))
         let format = [{day: 'numeric'}, {month: 'short'}];
         var started = new Date(game.started, format);
         var ended = new Date(game.ended);
         console.log("started: " + started + " ended: " + ended)
         …
     };
```

The first log call produces the expected values:

```
custom.js:16{"player":{"id":"6CCE3047-8080-4793-83C0-   C634C9E73AE1"},"score":34,"id":"4EA10020-79C6-46D0-AAD7-EC3E5C271E0D","moves":25,"match":{"id":"93D1319D-A258-4F9D-AC6E-B4860F95D948"},"updatedAt":649664452.29815102,"createdAt":649589977.37518704,"ended":null,"started":649661807.94521403}
```

This seems to be where my problems seem to begin. The numeric value for started seems unfamiliar: it's been transformed somehow from the original Postgres value, and I don't know what format this is.

The second log entry shows the value from the JSON, and the third one shows a date that is exactly 31 years before the correct, original date:

```
    Fri Aug 03 1990 12:36:47 GMT+0700 (+07)
```

The exact precision of 31 years seems like this is some formatting convention that I don't understand. Does anyone have any insight into what is going off the rails here?

The basic goal of this code – to update values on a page – is working fine when they don't involve dates.

EDIT: FYI, the schema from postgres:

```
    Column   |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |
 Default 
 ------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------  
id      | uuid                     |           | not null |   
match   | uuid                     |           | not null |   
player  | uuid                     |           | not null |   
started | timestamp with time zone |           |          |   
ended   | timestamp with time zone |           |          |   
score   | bigint                   |           |          |   
moves   | bigint                   |           |          |
created_at |timestamp with time zone |         |          |
updated_at |timestamp with time zone |         |          |
```

Comment: At https://www.epochconverter.com/  649589977 converts to Fri Aug 03 1990 12:36:47 GMT+0700 . So its working properly.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_time ? Check which reference date you handle?

Comment: What's this?  game.started * 1000

Comment: To clarify, if you print `payload` on the server side what values do you get for your date keys then?

Comment: What is the data type for the date field in Postgres? What is the data value shown in Postgres? In Postgres `select to_timestamp(649661807.94521403); 1990-08-02 22:36:47.945214-07`(in my time zone US/Pacific). Converting to milliseconds for JS `Date` yields the same result.

Comment: sorry for the delay – in Asia so see things late. @Grumpy, others: the date in the DB in postgres presents in formatted form, with the expected date, 31 years later. This is not the same date (now deleted from testing, but an entry looks like 2021-08-04 05:03:52.91689+00 in an sql search in the terminal.

Comment: @ElTomato: that's a multiplier for milliseconds; tried it without, and it's a date in 1970

Comment: the schema in postgres I am adding to the end of the question, to answer @AdrianKlaver

Comment: I don't use Swift, but I have to believe something is happening in Game/game or more probably in `JSONEncoder().encode(game)`. Look at the values before they get modified by either of the above.